# Can't get a Share Button to work in my iOS App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, button, share

I can't get a Share button to work in my current app, I successfully had one in my previous app but I can't get it to work in my new app. I think this may be due to my first app having only a single ViewController whereas this app has multiple. I am trying to do this in a different view controller, not the default main one. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
//  MoreMenuViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MoreMenuViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)tellFriend:(id)sender;


//  MoreMenuViewController.m

#import "MoreMenuViewController.h"

@implementation MoreMenuViewController

- (IBAction)tellFriend:(id)sender 
{   
    NSString *shareText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Check out Stories With Friends, a new word game for iPhone!"]; // Share message
    NSArray *itemsToShare = @[shareText];
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC =
    [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[];

    [MoreMenuViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

For the last line of code I get an error: No known class method for selector 'animated:completion:.'

Help would be much apperciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call this method from `self` instead of `MoreMenuViewController:`

```
[self presentViewController:activityVC
                   animated:YES
                 completion:nil];
```

You also don't need to call this setter if you don't need to excluded types:

```
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[];
```

UPDATE:

> Despite now being able to click the button the app crashes: -[MoreMenuViewController tellAFriend:]

It's because the name of your method is `tellFriend:` and NOT `tellAFriend:` you must had renamed your method from the code without refactoring so the linked IBAction has no clue of the change. What you need to do is remove this link made from your Storyboard to your implementation file.

Click on your button then click on the cross where the action is linked to `tellAFriend`:

[image]

Comment: No errors with that code but the button still doesn't work. You press it and nothing happens.

Comment: did you make sure the IBAction of your storyboard is connected to your implementation ?

Comment: Yes as in original post.

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: where are you calling this method ? in the main controller to display activityVC in an other view controller ? i'm sorry but I'm trying to understand

Comment: In another view controller (MoreMenuViewController). This code works in my old app which only has a single view controller.

Comment: Ok so I took autolayout constraints off the view controller and suddenly I am click buttons now. No idea why I couldn't before as they where all in place correctly with no errors. Despite now being able to click the button the app crashes:
-[MoreMenuViewController tellAFriend:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b4b4fd0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MoreMenuViewController tellAFriend:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b4b4fd0'

Comment: @George ok wait, I found the issue, i'll edit my answer

Comment: I had a duplicate IB, one being TellAFriend which was breaking it. So that and the autolayout is what caused this. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try `[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];`

instead